# Can no longer access scanner on Brother HL-L3290CDW scanner-printer-copier

Tags: scanner

My Brother "all in one" scanner-printer-copier was working fine for months with ubuntu 20.04 via USB cable.  I can still use the laser printer, but the first time I try to start a scan, it makes scanner noises for a few seconds and then the scanner program (xsane, gscan2pdf, or simplescan) says

```
sane_start: Invalid argument
```

On second and succeeding attempts I get

'brother4:bus2;dev1':invalid argument.

I suspect a permissions problem but don't know what exactly. I'm an applications programmer not a systems guy.  I don't know how these pieces connect.  What I have been able to find out is shown below:

```
sarg314@ralph: scanimage -L
device `brother4:bus2;dev1' is a Brother HL-L3290CDW USB scanner

sarg314@ralph:~$ scanimage --test
Output format is not set, using pnm as a default.
scanimage: open of device brother4:bus2;dev1 failed: Invalid argument
```

lsusb gives

```
sarg314@ralph:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 04f9:044a Brother Industries, Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 046d:c064 Logitech, Inc. M110 corded optical mouse (M-B0001)
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05af:8277 Jing-Mold Enterprise Co., Ltd AS2107
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 26ce:01a2 ASRock LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1058:1021 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. Elements Desktop (WDBAAU)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

So scanimage says it is bus2;dev1 and lsusb shows that as "Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub". That doesn't make sense, or am I misinterpretting this?

```
root@ralph:/home/sarg314# sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

found USB scanner (vendor=0x04f9 [Brother], product=0x044a [HL-L3290CDW series]) at libusb:003:006
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
could not fetch string descriptor: Pipe error
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.
```

Are the pipe errors my problem, or is that an irrelevant issue?

```
root@ralph:/home/sarg314# ls -l /dev/bus/usb/003
total 0
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 256 Sep 15 11:03 001
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 257 Sep 15 11:03 002
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 258 Sep 15 11:03 003
crw-rw-r--  1 root root 189, 259 Sep 15 11:03 004
crw-rw-r--+ 1 root lp   189, 261 Sep 15 11:03 006
```

Should the above command show a separate entry for a scanner device or does it all go through dev 6 on an all-in-one device like this?

```
root@ralph:/home/sarg314# getfacl /dev/bus/usb/003
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: dev/bus/usb/003
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: I think that `getfacl /dev/bus/usb/003/006` would show that your user would have permission to access the device. (If you have re-plugged the scanner the device will 007 or greater).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever information SANE gets is coming via the Brother scanner driver. It looks like the `scanimage -L` output is a bit of misinformation.

I do not do non-free drivers but will point you in the direction of a well-regarded and well-proven free one. It is what a user gets by default on Ubuntu 21.04.

First go [here](https://github.com/alexpevzner/sane-airscan) and then move on to [here](https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/pzz/xUbuntu_20.04/amd64/). Download and install **sane-airscan** and **ipp-usb**. No configuration required. Just plug in. Scanning should be immediately available.

I would be interested in the outputs from `scanimage -L` and `airscan-discover`. It will help other users.

Comment: Thanks for that information.  (I did try re-installing the Brother software to no avail.)  I will try the other driver.